# IntelliJ each module as separate jar-file

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9, artifact

I have 1 project and X modules. (main module and support modules)
How can i create an artifact which creates each module as separate jar files?
Do i have to mess around with the output layout?

[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE58R.png)

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmdPV.png)

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? The question is not clear over the modules and your structure either.

Comment: @nullpointer I have added some images to visualize my problem. I want each of the MVC component as separate jar-file

Comment: What I am not able to understand is why are you not able to generate jar of each module that you want? Whats the challenge that you're facing? Any framework like maven, gradle etc in use?

Comment: @nullpointer I want to generate them at once. Say if I compile VIEW, then its depencies Model und Controller should be generated as jar file as well. I am not familiar with other build tools. Maybe ant or gradle is more suitable for what I want to do.